# Python Finding multiple strings in between markers in a large paragraph

Tags: python

I'm trying to make lists of companies from long strings.

The company names tend to be randomly dispersed through the strings, but they always have a comma and a space before the names ', ', and they always end in Inc, LLC, Corporation, or Corp.

In addition, there is always a company listed at the very beginning of the string. It goes something like:

```
Companies = 'Apples Inc, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Bananas LLC, 
Carrots Corp, xxxx.'
```

I've been trying to use regex to crack this nut, but I am too inexperienced with python.

My closest attempt went like this:

```
r = re.compile(r' .*? Inc | .*? LLC | .*? Corporation | .*? Corp',
flags = re.I | re.X)

r.findall(Companies)
```

But my output is always some variation of

```
['Apples Inc', ', xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Bananas LLC', ', Carrots Corp']
```

When I need it to be like

```
['Apples Inc', 'Bananas LLC', 'Carrots Corp']
```

I am vexed and I humbly ask for assistance.

****EDIT

I have figured out a method to find the company name if it includes a comma, like Apples, Inc.

Before I run any analysis on the long string, I will have the program look if any commas exist 2 spaces before the Inc., and then delete them.

Then I will run the program to list out the company names.

Comment: The usual punctuation for a company name is `Company, Inc.`

Comment: Just split them up into individual strings then check if each string contains LLC, corp, etc

Comment: You haven't given it a reason to know that `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Bananas LLC` isn't a name of a company. You could make the condition that company names don't have commas (other than before the corp abbr) with `r'[^,]+?(?:Inc|LLC|Corp)'`

Comment: That punctuation isn't in the document I'm working with

Comment: No, someone commented that the usual punctuation goes Company, Inc., but in my document, it's always Company Inc,. The example is indicative of my data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a perfect example of when *not to use regex*. Your result can be achieved by just splitting the string based on commas and checking if the suffixes you specify exist in any of the divided segments.

For example:

```
paragraph = 'Apples Inc, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Bananas LLC, Carrots Corp, xxxx.'

suffixes = ["Inc", "Corp", "Corporation", "LLC"]

companies = []
#Split paragraph by commas
for term in paragraph.split(", "):
    #Go through the suffixes and see if any of them match with the split field
    for suffix in suffixes:
        if suffix in term:
            companies.append(term)

print(companies)
```

This code is a lot more readable and is probably a lot easier to understand than regex.

Comment: You can do this with a simple regex, and it suffers the same problem that the regex does -- it's a problem if the company has a comma in its name like `Dewey, Cheatem & Howe Inc`.

Comment: @Mark Based on the comments in the OP, it looks like there are no companies that follow that particular case. Although, I am curious as to how one might address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can do:

```
targets=('Inc', 'LLC', 'Corp', 'Corporation')

>>> [x for x in Companies.split(', ') if any(x.endswith(y) for y in targets)]
['Apples Inc', 'Bananas LLC', 'Carrots Corp']
```

This does not work if there is a `,` in the name or between the name and entity type however.

If you potentially have `Apple, Inc.` (which would be typical) you can do:

```
Companies = 'Apples, Inc., xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Bananas, LLC, Carrots Corp., xxxx.'


targets=('Inc', 'LLC', 'Corp', 'Corporation')

>>> re.findall(rf'([^,]+?(?:, )?(?:{"|".join(targets)})\.?)', Companies)
['Apples, Inc.', ' Bananas, LLC', ' Carrots Corp.']
```

[Demo and explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/MWODa3/1/)